# is this a cauchy sequence in $L^1$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n(x)$ = $nχ_{(\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}n]}$$(x)$  in $L^{1}[0,1]$

How should I proceed? I'm confused with the characteristic function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. We want that

$$
\left|\int_0^1 n \chi_{[\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}]} - m \chi_{[\frac{1}{m+1}, \frac{1}{m}]} \ dx \right| < \varepsilon.
$$

But 
$$
\left|\int_0^1 n \chi_{[\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}]} - m \chi_{[\frac{1}{m+1}, \frac{1}{m}]} \ dx \right| = \left|\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{m+1}\right| 
$$
Indeed, note that
$$
\int_0^1 n \chi_{[\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}]} \ dx = n \int_{1/(n+1)}^{1/n} 1 \ dx = n \left( \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1} \right) = \frac{1}{n + 1}
$$

Can you go from there?

Comment: Alright, I can go on from there, but, how did you compute the integral? that's where I'm confused.

Comment: I will edit my answer to add more steps, tell me if it is ok.

Comment: Now it's crystal clear!

Answer (score 1):

We can show $f_n$ converges to $0$ in $L^1$:

$$\int_0^1 |f_n-0| = \int_0^1 f_n = n\left (\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right ) = n\cdot\frac{1}{n(n+1)} = \frac{1}{n+1}\to 0.$$

Since convergent sequences in any metric space are Cauchy, $f_n$ is Cauchy in $L^1.$